# Can’t upload images from frontend of wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, image, web, upload, web-frontend

I am trying to create advertising portal. One of the main function of the website is uploading images of ads. Uploading images of ads is integrated in theme (it is not a plugin, it is default wordpress uploader). When I am not logged to the wp-admin and I want to upload image from frontend, an error occurs:[An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYdcA.png) I   tried to deactivate all plugins, changed permissions of upload file, checked the permissions of member roles and also checked the upload path. Do you know where can be the problem?

Comment: too few information. you're not logged in and trying to upload image into dashboard?

Comment: I am logged but not logged in wp-admin.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to upload the image if you're not using the Admin panel? A plugin? Custom code? As @SamvelAleqsanyan said, you really haven't given us enough information to help. I suggest you read [How to ask a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question so we have the information we need to help.